# i have a text file and want to extract spacific paragraph b/w two special line in php

Tags: php, regex, file, file-handling

I have this piece of code and want to extract data from the text file between two specific lines. I want to extract each section b/w those two lines. TEXT file example is here

```
---
 - ID: some random id

 \_______________________________\_
HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 1
\_______________________________\_
HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 2
\_______________________________\_
HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 3
\_______________________________\_
hello 
this is example text here
and i am section 4
```

here I have some code where I matched these lines but didn't find how to extract each section included the last section from a text file.

And need Output like this:

```
[0] => ' HELLO 
         This is an example text.
         I AM SECTION 1',
[1] => ' HELLO 
         This is an example text.
         I AM SECTION 2',
[2] => ' HELLO 
         This is an example text.
         I AM SECTION 3',
[3] => ' HELLO 
         This is an example text.
         I AM SECTION 4',


public static function find_section_in_file($file = '', $directory = '')
{
    $response = ['error' => true, 'section' => NULL];
    if (isset($file) && isset($directory)) {
        $handle = fopen($directory."\\".$file, "r");
        $section = [];
        if ($handle) {

            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                $new_line = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $line));
                $start = self::startsWith($new_line, '\__');
                $end = self::endsWith($new_line, '_\_');

                if ($start && $end){
                    array_push($section, $line);
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
            $response = ['error' => false, 'section' => $section];

        }
        //need To write Query to save section in DB
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: no i need each section section 1, 2, 3, 4 and also the last one

Comment: It would be useful if you added to your spec what the required output was

Comment: I want to extract each section b/w those two lines.

Comment: each section one by one ... from those lines can you please edit for me ....

Comment: I'm not well versed in php; so I don't know the functions for achieving this result; but I could tell you a procedure on how you could give it a try. 1. Grab the result from [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/KN9CEi/5) regex.2. Split on the basis of `\_______________________________\_`. 3.  join on ``. If I have to implement it in javascript; it would be something like [**this**](https://repl.it/@mAndY80SS/StaidBurlyPriorities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match all lines that do not start with the backslash/underscores line and capture those in capture group 1.

```
^\h*\\_+\\_\R((?:.*\R(?!\h*\\_+\\_).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*\\_+\\_\R` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars, `\` , 1+ underscores, `\`,  `_` and a unicode newline sequence
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `.*\R` Match the whole line and a newline
    - `(?!\h*\\_+\\_)` Negative lookahead, assert that the line does not start with the backslash/underscores
    - `.*` Match  Match the whole line
  - `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 1+ times
- `)` Close capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t3BAD6/1) | [php demo](https://3v4l.org/0rRUc)

For example

```
$re = '/^\h*\\\\_+\\\\_\R((?:.*\R(?!\h*\\\\_+\\\\_).*)*)/m';
$str = '---
 - ID: some random id

 \\_______________________________\\_
HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 1
\\_______________________________\\_
HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 2
\\_______________________________\\_
HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 3
\\_______________________________\\_
hello 
this is example text here
and i am section 4';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 1
    [1] => HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 2
    [2] => HELLO 
This is an example text.
I AM SECTION 3
    [3] => hello 
this is example text here
and i am section 4
)
```

Comment: this is a perfect answer, can you please guide me for one more thing.... how did I add the end line after each line, I have to save these into DB and after that in some cases have to send this on some Endpoints.

Comment: @عمررشید What do you mean by add the end line after each line?